# What does it mean if you add '&'before the variable, while declaring it?

Tags: c++, variables, variable-declaration

What is the difference between `int &r` and `int r`?

I'm new to this

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: @OWSam It's C++

Comment: You need to add this as a tag to the question then.

Comment: It defines a reference to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

First keep in mind that `int& r` and `int &r` are syntactically the same thing: `r` is a variable of type `int&`. So `r` is an integer reference.

To learn more about references in C++, there are plenty of online guides. Here's one: https://www.embedded.com/an-introduction-to-references/

Comment: So a reference is like a 'brother' or 'twin' of the original variable, which, when made changes to, will affect the original variable too?

Comment: The second half of your sentence is correct. But neither brothers nor twins work that way =)

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi • I'd call a reference (if not using the term "reference") an "alias" or "agnomen".

Comment: @tenfour Hah, maybe it's not a good analogy.